# Raster projection fails without error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, coordinate-system

I have a raster in one coordinate system (SC State Plane NAD83 NSRS2007) and need to project it to another (SC State Plane NAD83 HARN). When I run [Project Raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000007q000000), it fails silently: the dialog box output says "Succeeded," but no output is produced. Also, clicking "Close" on the dialog box brings the tool dialog back up, as it would if a tool failed to complete.

Without an error message, I am struggling to understand what the cause of the problem is, and how to circumvent or resolve it.

Comment: Assuming you're using feet as units, those two projections are literally identical (in effect). EPSG:3361 (HARN) and EPSG:3656 (NSRS2007). There's also a third projection out there that is identical to this one, EPSG:102719.

Comment: My concern is that I need to use it with ArcHydro tools, which tend to be extremely particular about projections (otherwise I'd just say "whatever" and move on)... Since they are essentially the same, I expected this to be a completely unremarkable part of the process.

Comment: Did you set a transformation? Although the tfm is a 'null' one (no changes), so you could just use Define Projection to change the metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this forum post](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=984&t=277237), I would try:

1. Checking your environment settings (extents, etc.)
2. Checking that you have chosen the correct transformation in the project raster tool.